# Best Practices for Form Handling in Next.js 14 using useFormState or react-hook-form?

Tags: next.js, react-hook-form

I'm working on a Next.js project and currently implementing form handling. I'm considering using either `useFormState` or `react-hook-form`, but I'm unsure which one to choose.

My current implementation is

```
 "use client"

import { zodResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/zod"
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form"
import { z } from "zod"
import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button"
import {
    Form,
    FormControl,
    FormField,
    FormItem,
    FormLabel,
    FormMessage,
} from "@/components/ui/form"
import { Input } from "@/components/ui/input"
import { CardWrapper } from "./card-wrapper"
import { LoginSchema } from "@/schemas"
import { login } from "@/actions/login"
import { startTransition, useState } from "react"


export function LoginForm() {
    const [error, setError] = useState<string | undefined>("");
    const [success, setSuccess] = useState<string | undefined>("");

    const form = useForm<z.infer<typeof LoginSchema>>({
        resolver: zodResolver(LoginSchema),
        defaultValues: {
            email: "",
            password: ""
        },
    })

    const onSubmit = (values: z.infer<typeof LoginSchema>) => {
        setError("");
        setSuccess("");

        startTransition(() => {
            login(values)
                .then((data) => {
                    setError(data?.error);
                    setSuccess(data?.success);
                });
        });
    }

    return (
        <CardWrapper
            headerLabel="Welcome back "
            backButtonLabel="Don't have an account?"
            backButtonHref="/auth/register"
            showSocial
        >
            <Form {...form}>
                <form onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)} className="space-y-8">
                    <FormField
                        control={form.control}
                        name="email"
                        render={({ field }) => (
                            <FormItem>
                                <FormLabel>Email</FormLabel>
                                <FormControl>
                                    <Input placeholder="email" {...field} />
                                </FormControl>
                                <FormMessage />
                            </FormItem>
                        )}
                    />
                   // field for password
                    <Button className="w-full" type="submit">Submit</Button>
                </form>
                <p>{error}</p>
                <p>{success}</p>
            </Form>
        </CardWrapper>
    )
}
```

but I can use useFormState react-dom hook which will provide me state of the form as well as server Action , also I can use useFormStatus to show pending state instead of startTransition.

here I want to know how can I do form handling in better way?
What are the key differences between useFormState and react-hook-form in the context of Next.js?
which should I use in which scenario?